# Are video card resolution specs per-display or overall total when using multiple displays?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, 4k-resolution

I'm an avid user of multiple monitors and have been contemplating an upgrade to a couple of 4k monitors. However I'm not sure how to interpret my video card specs or the specs of other cards I might have to get. Most cards specify the maximum resolution, but it isn't readily apparent whether this is per display or an overall maximum renderable area.

For example I have a card based on the [GTX 650 Ti](http://www.nvidia.in/object/geforce-gtx-650ti-in.html#pdpContent=2) chipset that claims to be able to drive 3840x2160 at 30Hz. This is the size and speed of the monitor I was looking at—bit while my card has four outputs, somehow I wonder if it is up for driving 2ea 4k displays. Would that spec resolution be per-display or an overall total across multiple displays?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are exceptions to this depending on the system, OS, and approach used in general, but I'm going to have to go with, as a general rule, saying that resolution is on a per display basis. I remember using a 19" CRT running 1600x1200, with a 15" @ 1024x768 way back, having two gfx adapters with Windows 2000.

Comment: Your anecdotal evidence is exactly the opposite of what I'm asking. I have **one** GFX adapter, and in fact a typical way of using the DVI ports on these sorts of cards is in a dual-link configuration.

Comment: @Caleb I did the same with a single GFX card with two outputs, and I was able to set individual resolutions for each of them.

Comment: up to a total the max speced res of the card on each port or up to a total where the overall rendered area is less than the total max spec?

Comment: @Caleb I cannot say, my resolutions bottlenecked at both of the screens. I think I remember the card advertising up to 2048xSomething